# Designer tool to generate pdf reports using Aspose pdf for .Net

Tags: .net, aspose

Is there any designer tool (like XAML designer/Blend for Windows metro apps) available for designing Aspose reports format in .Net? Or we have to manually design each row, each section and each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspose.Pdf for .NET is an API which you can use in your code to create, edit, or convert PDF files dynamically. It is not a graphical tool to create PDF files using some UI elements. If you need to create PDF files manually then you can try Adobe Acrobat etc. With [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx), you can create PDF files in your code using text, images, data from database, and other objects.

Answer (score 1):

We designed the template in Excel, filled data and saved it as Pdf using Aspose.Cells.

Its a bit late but I hope it helps others.